# graphviz with combined edges

Tags: graph-theory, graphviz

I'm looking for a way to achieve something like this in graphviz:

```
          --- node B 
          |
node A ---
          |
          --- node C
```

another example (at the bottom):  http://machining.grundfos.de/media/60727/grundfos_pumpenhandbuch.pdf#23

Is there a way of doing that with graphviz?

so far I only got orthogonal edges:

```
digraph G {
 graph [rankdir=LR,splines=ortho,concentrate=true];
 node [shape=box,];
 edge [dir=none];

 a -> b;
 a -> c;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you must introduce intermediate (eventually hidden) nodes to act as split points.
For instance:

```
digraph G {
 graph [rankdir=LR,splines=ortho,concentrate=true];
 node [shape=box,];
 edge [dir=none];
 i [shape=point];
 a -> i -> b;
 a -> i -> c;
}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: you can add width=0 to the options of i:
i [shape=point,width=0];